# Installing Mod_Security on CentOS

Tags: centos, mod-security

I recently switched to a VPS rather than shared hosting. One of the helpful things of shared hosting was having mod_security. I noticed whenever I was trying to prevent SQL injections it's always a nice thing to add on. Anyways, I went to [this site](http://www.modsecurity.org/download.html) and followed the instructions for CentOS. Then I changed my configuration file to have SecEngineRule ON. I'm not sure if this was all I have to do, but I looked at a tutorial and this was all it said to do. However, after I restarted my server I went to attempt SQL injection on my site and Mod Security didn't do anything like it normally does. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely you did not activated any rules, also, you might have forgotten to load mod_sec - which is good in this case, as you should switch `SecEngineRule ON` only AFTER you tested the config as you otherwise end up pretty fast in locking your web server down too much giving you a hard time...

Check this guide: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-mod_security-with-the-owasp-core-rule-set-on-a-centos-vps/

The guide describes to install mod_sec from source (which will give you the latest version rather the one you got using yum with standard repos.

For the last step mentioned in guide above:
Use `systemctl start httpd` if you are on CentOS 7 and don´t forget to run  `systemctl enable httpd` in orderto make sure http is loaded after a reboot.

[Another, more detailed, guide](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-apache-using-mod_security-and-mod_evasive-on-rhel-centos-fedora/) covers configuring mod_sec and (if wanted) mod_evasive. However, that guide ignores the mod_unique_id - so simply merge the two guides provided and you should be good to go.